# Spring security concurrent-session and HttpSessionListener problem

Tags: spring, spring-security, httpsession

I have implemented HttpSessionListener and it works fine except for the case when a logged in user concurrently logs in a second time. Spring terminates the first session correctly, but the destroySession event is never fired, at least my listener never gets it.

My spring-security is as follows:

```
<session-management 
    session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" >

<concurrency-control 
    max-sessions="1"
    expired-url="/login_sessionexpired" />
</session-management>
```

The above logs the user out of the first session, if they concurrently log in a second time, however, the HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed is never called.

The HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed is called normally for manual logout and session time out.

I have a 'delegating proxy' for the listener in web.xml:
    
        com.test.security.DelegatingHttpSessionEventListenerProxy

This listener delegates to a spring-bean defined in the my-servlet.xml as:

```
<bean id="httpSessionEventListener"
    class="com.test.security.SimpleHttpSessionEventListenerImpl" />
```

The delegating listener is coded as:

```
public class DelegatingHttpSessionEventListenerProxy implements
    HttpSessionListener {

/**
 * Delegates sessionCreated Event to the Spring-bean
 */
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getWebApplicationContext(se.getSession().getServletContext());

    HttpSessionListener target = context.getBean(
            "httpSessionEventListener", HttpSessionListener.class);
    target.sessionCreated(se);
}

/**
 * Delegates sessionDestroyed Event to the Spring-bean
 */
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getWebApplicationContext(se.getSession().getServletContext());

    HttpSessionListener target = context.getBean(
            "httpSessionEventListener", HttpSessionListener.class);
    target.sessionDestroyed(se);
}
}
```

I'm using spring-security-3.0.5, can somebody please tell me what am I missing?
Thank you.

Comment: Luke Taylor, from Acegi Security System TeamSpring Team:

The session will only be invalidated if the user tries to use it again after starting a new session, otherwise it will time out as normal. This is because it isn't possible to invalidate a session other than during a request made as part of that session. At least not without resorting to container-specific APIs.

Comment: where did luke say this?

Comment: I asked this question on Spring's security forum too. He answered over there, thought it would be beneficial if his reply is shared.

Comment: Forum thread is at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?110673-Spring-security-concurrent-session-and-HttpSessionListener-problem