# Httpsessionlistener: two sessions are created and none are destroyed

Tags: spring, comet, server-push, httpsession

## Edit: I reformulated the question

I'm using `Spring` and `GWTEventService` (which is basicly the same as `Comet`). When I make a simpler HttpSessionListener, I see **sessionCreated() is called twice and sessionDestroyed()** is not called in between. Why is that? Do I have two sessions for one user???
The second `HttpSession` is created when I set some information for the first time at a session bean (`Spring`).

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
 
public class SomeSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
 
  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    log.info("New session was created, source= " + se.getSource());
  }
 
  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    log.info("A session was closed");
  } 
}
```

Example Output:

```
Application has started
New session was created, source= org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager$Session:21u4n0rnyp4i@24662444
New session was created, source= org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager$Session:n9wm8tsj1ote@28925695
Application interrupted by client
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer formulated to a different question:
[Spring security concurrent-session and HttpSessionListener problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347835/spring-security-concurrent-session-and-httpsessionlistener-problem?rq=1#comment7429710_6347835)

In short:
**It's better to a destroy-method to the session bean.**